# Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a method in a client server program which is meant to create an instance of a citylist class, which is just an array list of cities...

(This method is in server)

```
public void listCities() {
    CityList LoadCities = new CityList();
    String CityDetails = LoadCities.cities.toString();
    try {
        dos.writeUTF("These are the cities serviced by the ssystem");
        dos.writeUTF(ServerConstants.CR_LF);
        dos.writeUTF(CityDetails);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

The CityList Class is this:

```
public class CityList {

public ArrayList<City> cities;
    City melbourne = new City("Melbourne");
    City sydney = new City("Sydney");
    City darwin = new City("Darwin");
    City launceston = new City("Launceston");
    City hobart = new City("Hobart");

//default constructor
public CityList() {
    cities.add(melbourne);
    cities.add(sydney);
    cities.add(darwin);
    cities.add(launceston);
    cities.add(hobart);
}


//other constructor
public CityList(ArrayList<City> cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
}

public int size()
{
    return cities.size();
}



}
```

The client exists in a thread... The server calls a socket handler in its own thread class SocketHandler extends Thread 
    class SocketHandler extends Thread

I continually get this error when I try to call that particular method (list cities)

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at hotelbroker.CityList.<init>(CityList.java:30)
at hotelbroker.SocketHandler.listCities(MultiEchoServer.java:153)
at hotelbroker.SocketHandler.run(MultiEchoServer.java:95)
```

I know this is cuz I'm a n00b and I need to call some kind of this instance thingummy I just have no idea...

Comment: `public ArrayList<City> cities;` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't initialize instance fields, they get initialized to `null` by default. In this case, you are trying to use this instance variable

```
public ArrayList<City> cities;
```

without having first intialized it. It's therefore `null`.

When you try to invoke a method on a `null` reference, like here

```
cities.add(melbourne);
```

you get a `NullPointerException`.

You have to initialize it, either where it is declared

```
public ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
```

or before you use it

```
cities = new ArrayList<>();
cities.add(melbourne);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public CityList() {
    cities = new ArrayList<City>();
    cities.add(melbourne);
    cities.add(sydney);
    cities.add(darwin);
    cities.add(launceston);
    cities.add(hobart);
}
```